# How do I manipulate variable names in R functions?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I would like to write a function that generates variable names according to the arguments and uses them (successfully).

E.g.,

```
df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                   A2 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

```
sum(df_a$A1)
sum(df_a$A2)
```

The above should be done using the following function:

```
fun_a <- function(x) {
  df <- paste0("df_a$A", x)
  sum(get(df))
}
```

But testing this...

```
fun_a(1)
fun_a(2)
```

...throws an error:

```
Error in get(df) : object 'df_a$A1' not found
```

Does this mean my global variable is not recognized or not accessible?

And how can I solve this?

Please, elaborate - I really want to understand how this works!

Comment: Use `paste0("x_a$A", x)`, x is the argument of your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` does not work in your case because the object `df_a$A1` does not exist. 
`df_a` exists and has a column `A1` but this is not how `get` works.

In your case you can use `paste` to only select the right column:

```
fun_a <- function(x) {
  sum(df_a[, paste0("A", x)])
}

> fun_a(1)
[1] 6
> fun_a(2)
[1] 8
```

In a more general setting you could use `get` to get the right dataframe and then use paste to select the right column of that dataframe.

Alternatively, you can use `summarise_at` from the `dplyr` package to do just that:

```
fun_a <- function(x) {
  as.numeric(dplyr::summarise_at(df_a, x, sum))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the dataframe to the function and then use `eval` `parse`

```
fun_a <- function(df_a, x) {
   df <- paste0("df_a$A", x)
   sum(eval(parse(text = df)))
}

fun_a(df_a, 1)
#[1] 4
```

However, you should ***really not do this***. There are much better way you can handle data and pass columns in function. One quick way would be

```
fun_a <- function(df_a, x) {
   sum(df_a[[x]])
}
fun_a(df_a, 2)
#[1] 5
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                   A2 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the column name  to get the column value.
`get()` function only use the object name to return the value of the object.

```
df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                   A2 = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
fun_a <- function(x) {
  df <- paste0("A", x)
  sum(get("df_a")[df])
}

sum(df_a$A1)

fun_a(1)
```

Comment: You don't need to load magrittr here

Comment: @alan ocallaghan Works without magrittr

Comment: Yes, I did check before I commented - I've made that mistake before :)